# How to move an 2D character(with animation) to mouse click position in C#?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

i am going to develop a simple game called waste collection.In which if i click on a waste the character needs to walk to certain waste and collect it.Startingly the character is in the middle position of the screen.when we click on the left side of the character,animation left walk needs to play.On the other hand,when we click on the right side of the character the animation right walk needs to play.How the clicked position is taken in this application and how the character animates to that clicked position

```
public class mousepos : MonoBehaviour {

private Animator anim;
 public float speed = 1.5f;
 private Vector3 target;

 void Start () {
 anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
     target = transform.position;
 }

 void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                    if (**Input.mousePosition.x <= 500**) { //move skeleton on X axis to the left
                            target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
                            target.z = transform.position.z;
                            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1); 
                            anim.SetInteger ("Direction", 1);

                    } else if (Input.mousePosition.x >= 500) {

                            target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
                            target.z = transform.position.z;
                            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1); 
                            anim.SetInteger ("Direction", 1);
                    }

            }
     transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,              target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
 }    
 }
```

Comment: do you mean that your character directly jumps to the place clicked and doesn't move in animation?

Comment: no.. i do not mean that ... i want to move my character towards the cursor direction as like normal human walk.

Comment: It is unclear what problem you have. Do you have a problem with how the character goes to the target (like speed of movement etc) or do you have problems with starting/stopping the animation when the character moves?

Comment: i need different animations (left animation and right animation). When i click on left side of the scene,it should play leftwalk animation . clik on right side of the scene  play right walk animation. How to identify these cliked position.

Comment: Please, try to formulate your question in these terms: (1) what are you trying to achieve, (2) what have you done so far, (3) what's happening now and (4) what's exactly confusing or unclear to you right now.

Comment: @Max Yankov: ok please check it now. In the above code one side animation is working.

Comment: And what's wrong with how the code above works? You say that the so called "left animation" works, but I see you flip the scale of the object on the x axis, so you should see a proper animation of going right. Put a `Log.Debug("left if activated");` line in the proper if to see if your check condition is wrong. If so, simply compare the players x position and the targets x position. If the difference is > 0, go left, else go right.

Comment: yes you are right ...but  error         Operator `<=' cannot be applied to operands of type `float' and `UnityEngine.Vector3'                                             if (Input.mousePosition.x <=target) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking for but would something like this work?

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
    target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    target.z = transform.position.z;
    if(target.x > transform.position.x) transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1); 
    else if(target.x < transform.position.x) transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    anim.SetInteger ("Direction", 1);
 } 
 transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it ..:)

public class mousepos : MonoBehaviour {

```
    private Animator anim;
    public float speed = 1.5f;
    private Vector3 target;
    private Vector3 MousePosition;
    private Vector3 PlayerPosition;
    void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();


    target = transform.position;

    }
    void Update () {

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

            target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
           target.z = transform.position.x;

           Debug.Log ("traaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" + target.z);
           if (target.x <= target.z) {


          transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1); 
         anim.SetInteger ("Direction", 1);

    }
   else if (target.x >= target.z) {

                            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1); 
                            anim.SetInteger ("Direction", 1);
                    }



            }

      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    }
```